# What are the most used divisibility theorems?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Consider the questions of type :

Does $x$ divide $y$ ?

What are the most used divisibility theorems to decide such matters ?

Fermat’s little , quadratic and cubic reciprocity and $gcd(x,y) = gcd(x,x-y)$ are probably the most used.

What are the next most used or most useful ones ?

Btw I consider integers only here , So No  gaussian integers or ring extensions.

Comment: Euler's theorem perhaps ? It generalizes Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: Yes and biquadratic reciprocity , quintic reciprocity etc :)

Comment: Catalan Numbers and euler Numbers seem related. ( Catalan Numbers are always integers despite Being defined by fractions ! )